# functions run but templating doesn't populate

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am learning vue by making some widgets on my website. I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rubidious0xide/ygraLt4q/) that rolls two four-sided dice and prints the results. Seems simple enough to me:

```
<div id="app">
  <p class="helpertxt">{{ introtxt }}</p>
  <button id="roll-btn" v-on:click="rolladie">ROLL</button>
  <textarea id="die-res" cols="50" rows="3" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

The vue instance lists a simple msg.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    introtxt: 'Version 1.0 rolls 2d4. Press the button!'
  },
  methods: {
    rolladie: function(){
        var res1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        var res2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        var tres = 'You rolled ' + res1 + ', ' + res2;
        document.getElementById("die-res").innerHTML = tres;
        }
    }
})
```

What I don't understand is why the message populates on JSFiddle but does not populate on [my website](https://androme.de/tools/). Why is it that the function works but the message does not insert on the template?

Comment: I can see the message in your website without problems when I press the roll button

Comment: Not sure why it's not working on your website, but you're circumventing Vue's functionality by directly accessing the `innerHTML` like that. You should have a data property (say `resultMsg`) and bind it to the textarea via `v-model="resultMsg"` and then in you `rolladie` function, simply set `this.resultMsg = tres;`

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in Chrome dev tools and see if the functions are being called?